# Which primes intersect the submonoid $f^\mathbb{N}(1+fA)\subset A$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $f\in A,I\vartriangleleft A$. We have obvious submonoids $f^\mathbb{N},1+I\subset A$.

- The submonoid $f^\mathbb{N}\subset A$ is saturated, and its complement is the union of primes **not containing** $f$.
- The complement of the saturation of the submonoid $1+I\subset A$ is the union of **maximal** ideals **containing** $I$.

**Question.** Which primes of $A$ (do not) intersect the submonoid $f^\mathbb{N}(1+fA)$? (here $fA=(f)\vartriangleleft A$.)

Comment: $f^{\mathbb{N}}$ is typically not saturated (for instance, consider if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ is composite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a prime $P$ intersects $f^\mathbb{N}(1+fA)$ iff it intersects either $f^\mathbb{N}$ or $1+fA$.  This happens iff either $f\in P$ or $f$ is a unit mod $P$.

So, $P$ does not intersect $f^\mathbb{N}(1+fA)$ iff $f$ is nonzero and not a unit mod $P$.  Equivalently, this means that $P$ can be extended to both prime ideals that contain $f$ and prime ideals that don't.  Algebro-geometrically, if $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is a variety, then such primes $P$ are the generic points of subvarieties which intersect but are not contained in the vanishing set of $f$.

Comment: Is this set of primes anything like the boundary of $\mathbf{V}(f)\subset\operatorname{Spec}A$?

Comment: It's certainly not the boundary in the Zariski topology; $V(f)$ is closed so it contains its own boundary (whereas none of these primes are in $V(f)$).  You could say it's the boundary of $V(f)$ in the reverse specialization order topology, where you say a set is open iff it is specialiization-closed.

Comment: I ask because $\mathfrak p$ specializes to a closed point of $D(f)$ and to a closed point of $\mathbf{V}(f)$, and I imagined this as $\mathfrak p$ "floating over the boundary". I would appreciate a corrected picture if you have one! (And thanks for the answer as always.)

Comment: Your picture is good, but it doesn't correspond to the topological notion of boundary.  This is a weird phenomenon that can only happen in non-$T_1$ spaces, so it's not going to be a topological concept that is familiar from nice spaces.

Comment: Interestingly, the submonoid $f^\mathbb{N}(1+fA)$ intersects any maximal ideals, so the spectrum of its localization (thought of as a subset) does not contain any of the closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. Strange stuff...